# React Image src undefined - AWS S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a:

```js
<img src={ "http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/users/profile_photo/" + user.profile_photo }
     className="img-fluid rounded-circle"
     alt="rounded image"/>
```

Whenever I load in the page, the function `getUser()` runs and retrieves the user.

```js
const getUser = async () => {
  let user = await axiosWithAuth().get('/users/' + userId);
  setUser(user.data);
};
```

`user.profile_photo` is the key that I get back from AWS s3. ex. `43256722324654`

The Problem:
When the page loads, the image src is not yet set from what it looks like because, in the express backend, the profile_photo comes through undefined. It becomes defined on the second go around.

Because of this AWS throws an error for `noSuchKey`

> /Users/timbogdanov/Desktop/hlam/server/node_modules/AWS-SDK/lib/request.js:31
> throw err;
> ^

> NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.

Is there any way to stop the image from sending the get request until the user state object is set?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition to render the image. If `user.profile_photo` is not defined don't render it.

```
{user.profile_photo && <img src={ "http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/users/profile_photo/" + user.profile_photo }
     className="img-fluid rounded-circle"
     alt="rounded image"/>
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, I don't know how I missed this. And thank you for the edit!